# In jQuery, what's the proper way to "move" an element from its parent to another element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

#### Using jQuery 1.4 and jQueryUI 1.8

Specifically, I'm using draggables/droppables, and when dropped, I would like to move the draggable (it's children, events, etc) from belonging to its parent element to be appended/added as a child of the drop target.

I know that in the droppable `drop` option, I can supply the following callback:

```
function(event, ui) {
    // stuff
}
```

where `$(this).target` will be the drop target, and `ui.draggable` will be the child element I would like to move - but I'm not sure the proper way to actually perform the move, preserving events, etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append) will remove the element and place it where you want.

```
$(this).target.append(ui.draggable);

// or, if $(this).target is not a jQuery object

var target = $(this).target;
$(target).append(ui.draggable);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `.append()`, `.appendTo()`, `.prepend()` or `.prependTo()`.  The detaching part is implicit.  (I tested this by re-parenting entries in the jQuery Manipulation docs to each other.)

```
ui.draggable.appendTo($(this).target);
```